# Which Sacred Books Require Burial?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names, disposal

A straightforward question: can anybody please source for me a full discussion of which seforim require burial and which do not. (By way of an example, I have heard it said that a gemara need not be buried since it contains no tetragrammata [4 letter name of Hashem].)

Comment: To clarify: I assume you are referring to the Shem Havaya, since the names of Elokus (e.g. Bava Basra 15b) and Adnus (e.g. Berachos 7b) appear frequently in the Talmud.