# How to bury old s'farim

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names, funeral-burial-levaya, disposal

Suppose I have a printed *Chumash* with *Rashi*, or [the like](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25654), which is worn out to the point of inutility, and I wish to discard it. My understanding (based in part on sources I supply below) is that I must bury it. How do I do so? Can I, for example, simply put it in a hole in my backyard?

I see that *Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 154:5, says a worn *sefer Tora* must be buried in an earthenware receptacle with a *talmid chacham*, and the *Chasam Sofer* there says a wooden receptacle is as good or better. I see, also, that *Magen Avraham* extends this rule to any holy book: but I don't know whether he's extending only the burial requirement or also the in-an-earthen-receptacle and/or the with-a-*talmid-chacham* requirement. (I'm also not 100% sure he means any holy book: perhaps only *Nach* scrolls? The word he uses is "*s'farim*".) Finally, I see that the *Mishb'tzos Zahav* there says he hasn't seen the with-a-*talmid-chacham* requirement practiced, even for *sifre Tora*.

So what do I do with my *Chumash*? (I know I should ask my rabbi for practical *halacha*: I'm here seeking only further sources and logical arguments.)

Comment: Somewhat related (and maybe somebody who answers this question would like to also answer the other): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25654/which-sacred-books-require-burial